# What is the most efficient way to persist thousands of entities?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have fairly large CSV files which I need to parse and then persist into PostgreSQL. For example, one file contains 2_070_000 records which I was able to parse and persist in ~8 minutes (single thread). Is it possible to persist them using multiple threads?

```java
    public void importCsv(MultipartFile csvFile, Class<T> targetClass) {
        final var headerMapping = getHeaderMapping(targetClass);
        File tempFile = null;

        try {
            final var randomUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            tempFile = File.createTempFile("data-" + randomUuid, "csv");
            csvFile.transferTo(tempFile);

            final var csvFileName = csvFile.getOriginalFilename();
            final var csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
            log.info("Starting to import {}", csvFileName);
            final var csvRecords = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withDelimiter(';')
                    .withHeader(headerMapping.keySet().toArray(String[]::new))
                    .withSkipHeaderRecord(true)
                    .parse(csvReader);

            final var models = StreamSupport.stream(csvRecords.spliterator(), true)
                    .map(record -> parseRecord(record, headerMapping, targetClass))
                    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

           // How to save such a large list? 

            log.info("Finished import of {} in {}", csvFileName, stopWatch);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            tempFile.delete();
        }
    }
```

**models** contains a lot of records. The parsing into records is done using parallel stream, so it's quite fast. I'm afraid to call **SimpleJpaRepository.saveAll**, because I'm not sure what it will do under the hood.

The question is: What is the most efficient way to persist such a large list of entities?

P.S.: Any other improvements are greatly appreciated.

Comment: target db have schema designed with different columns corresponding to csv columns?

Comment: Use the [CopyManager API](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html)  which is a Java wrapper around `copy ... from stdin`

Comment: It looks like a operational action. If you are developing a operational service this is ok, otherwise you better not write code for this administrative task.

Comment: Ditch the stream, use a classic for loop. Save every individual item and every x items (say 100) do a flush and clear of the entitymanager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use batch inserts.

1. Create an interface for a custom repository `SomeRepositoryCustom`

```java
public interface SomeRepositoryCustom {

    void batchSave(List<Record> records);

}
```

2. Create an implementation of `SomeRepositoryCustom`

```java
@Repository
class SomesRepositoryCustomImpl implements SomeRepositoryCustom {

    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public SomesRepositoryCustomImpl(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public void batchSave(List<Record> records) {
        final String sql = "INSERT INTO RECORDS(column_a, column_b) VALUES (?, ?)";

        template.execute(sql, (PreparedStatementCallback<Void>) ps -> {
            for (Record record : records) {
                ps.setString(1, record.getA());
                ps.setString(2, record.getB());
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
            return null;
        });
    }

}
```

3. Extend your `JpaRepository` with `SomeRepositoryCustom`

```java
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository, SomeRepositoryCustom {

}
```

to save

`someRepository.batchSave(records);`

**Notes**

Keep in mind that, if you are even using batch inserts, database driver will not use them. For example, for MySQL, it is necessary to add a parameter `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to database URL.
So better to enable driver SQL logging (not Hibernate) to verify everything. Also can be useful to debug driver code.

You will need to make decision about splitting records by packets in the loop

```java
    for (Record record : records) { 

    }
```

A driver can do it for you, so you will not need it. But better to debug this thing too.

P. S. Don't use `var` everywhere.

Comment: You can do it easier with JPA you don't need SQL for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum how? Can you share a link?