# JPA/Hibernate performance improvement for bulk insert and fetch

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring boot 2 with JPA/hibernate.
I am reading an excel file using Apache POI and saving it into DB, and fetching records from DB to show on UI.

APP UI is similar to an excel sheet where users can search records, add, delete, insert rows/columns.

Everything is working fine for small sheets but large sheets take time in both insert records or to get data from DB.

So far I have tried the following things -

**GET request -**

- Implement Ehcache, work for the single server but on prod, we have multiple servers so need to setup Distributed or Replicated Caching,

**Post Request**

- Tried with batch processing but we are using GenerationType.IDENTITY so the batch process will not work and to change it SEQUENCE will take time as it required DB change.

Is there anything that I can try other than caching and batch process?
We are using IBM DB2 database

Comment: did you try setting batch size? for fetch did you add indexing?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera tried batch insert but not worked with GenerationType.IDENTITY.
for fetch did you add indexing -- not yet, will try it

Comment: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true`

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts

Answer (score 0):

**Post Request**

Use batch inserts on the JDBC level.

[What is the most efficient way to persist thousands of entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467407/3405171)

Hibernate doesn't participate at that level, so it is possible to use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

[Why does Hibernate disable INSERT batching when using an IDENTITY identifier generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27732138/3405171)

**Get request**

1. Use paging, a user don't usually need all the data at once.
2. Use projections.